# How to diagnose Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS?

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

When we install through (diawi) IPA link, on button action application crashes but not when we run application through Xcode in device on button action.

Please go through the crash log

```
Incident Identifier: FBD22F68-8100-4C4B-AF0B-E7CC904B76E6
CrashReporter Key:   72551bfef42a0d2c859adaf0adc11a7785bf1e5a
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             App Name [1136]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C6BDB9F3-0B9B-493D-9FA4-B7B2DB37ED5E/appName.app/AppName
Identifier:          com.myCo.aapName
Version:             1.2 (1.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-12-03 15:18:16.16 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-12-03 15:18:02.02 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
12.528842    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185ad1a18 TCP Conn 0x145697ac0 SSL Handshake DONE
13.177001    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185ad1928 TCP Conn 0x145697ac0 starting SSL negotiation
13.177393    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185b73a30 TCP Conn 0x145697ac0 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
13.178794    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185b74f5c TCP Conn 0x145697ac0 event 1. err: 0
13.538311    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185b75034 TCP Conn 0x145697ac0 started
13.557055    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185bca608 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
13.557055    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185bca5d4 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
13.557055    CFNetwork                  0x0000000185c1c394 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019af9c158 0x19af7c000 + 131416
1   UIKit                           0x000000018b983a30 0x18b94c000 + 227888
2   UIKit                           0x000000018b99b590 0x18b94c000 + 325008
3   UIKit                           0x000000018b953ff4 0x18b94c000 + 32756
4   UIKit                           0x000000018b9946cc 0x18b94c000 + 296652
5   UIKit                           0x000000018b993cc8 0x18b94c000 + 294088
6   UIKit                           0x000000018b9644a4 0x18b94c000 + 99492
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b96276c 0x18b94c000 + 92012
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186388544 0x1862ac000 + 902468
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186387fd8 0x1862ac000 + 901080
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186385cd8 0x1862ac000 + 892120
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001862b4ca0 0x1862ac000 + 36000
12  GraphicsServices                0x00000001914f0088 0x1914e4000 + 49288
13  UIKit                           0x000000018b9ccffc 0x18b94c000 + 528380
14  WealthCalculator                0x00000001000a84cc 0x100094000 + 83148
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019b7d28b8 0x19b7d0000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8f04fc 0x19b8d4000 + 115964
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b7b4a04 0x19b7a0000 + 84484
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b7a3874 0x19b7a0000 + 14452

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 7 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8d6598 0x19b8d4000 + 9624
1   WealthCalculator                0x00000001001949d8 0x100094000 + 1051096
2   WealthCalculator                0x0000000100183e50 0x100094000 + 982608
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7b28 0x19b9b4000 + 15144
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7a8c 0x19b9b4000 + 14988
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5028 0x19b9b4000 + 4136

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8efb6c 0x19b8d4000 + 113516
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5530 0x19b9b4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5020 0x19b9b4000 + 4128

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8d4a40 0x19b8d4000 + 2624
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8d48bc 0x19b8d4000 + 2236
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186388108 0x1862ac000 + 901384
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186385e0c 0x1862ac000 + 892428
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001862b4ca0 0x1862ac000 + 36000
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000185b4db84 0x185aa0000 + 711556
6   Foundation                      0x0000000187313c80 0x187220000 + 998528
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7b28 0x19b9b4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7a8c 0x19b9b4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5028 0x19b9b4000 + 4136

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019b8ef368 0x19b8d4000 + 111464
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018638e670 0x1862ac000 + 927344
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7b28 0x19b9b4000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b7a8c 0x19b9b4000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019b9b5028 0x19b9b4000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100000000   x1: 0x000000018c336aa1   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x000000016fd68038
    x4: 0x000000016fd68038   x5: 0x000000019de15b80   x6: 0x0000000145728a20   x7: 0x00000000000006f0
    x8: 0x0000000000000004   x9: 0x000000014566b1f0  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000145826c10  x13: 0x000005a1002e230f  x14: 0x00000000000000c8  x15: 0x000000018c4767bd
   x16: 0x000000018c336aa1  x17: 0x000000018c1e1064  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001a15e3000
   x20: 0x0000000145594fb0  x21: 0x0000000000000040  x22: 0x00000001455bdbe0  x23: 0x00000001001d8d69
   x24: 0x0000000146839a40  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x000000018c33588c
   x28: 0x0000000100000000  fp: 0x000000016fd695d0   lr: 0x000000018b983a30
    sp: 0x000000016fd69530   pc: 0x000000019af9c158 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Any guesses why I am getting this error? Somebody knows how to fix this issue?
Will you please help me out to overcome this problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same device in both cases?

Comment: @IrfanGul YES, I am. Its working fine in all devices connected to system (Xcode) but through link when we try to download in device its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code previous when application was getting crashed is

```
int registerNumber = (int)nil;

Bool success = [[NSScanner scannerWithString:registerNumberInputTextField.text] scanInteger:&registerNumber];
```

After, I change my code to

```
Bool success = [[NSScanner scannerWithString:registerNumberInputTextField.text] scanInt:&registerNumber];
```

Because I was pointing `int` value to `NSInteger` and that was crashing my application so I changed code as mentioned above and now it is working properly.